# How do I keep state persistant using local storage, react hooks, and Context Provider

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm implementing authentication into my app, the issue I am having is on refresh the state is not persistent so I get redirected back to the login screen. How can I use React Hooks to check if there is an **authToken** in `local storage` to keep me logged in on refresh.

This is **My Protected Route** That checks for auth tokens

```
<Route
    {...rest}
    render={
        props=>
            authTokens ? (
                <Component {...props}/>
            ) : (
                <Redirect
                    to ={
                        {
                            pathname: '/login',
                            state: {
                                from: props.location
                            }
                        }
                    }
                />
```

This is my **Login page** Function

```
 function Login(props) {
const [isLoggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);
const [firstName, setUserName] = useState("");
const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
const { setAuthTokens } = useAuth();

function postLogin() {
    axios.post("http://10.6.254.22:5000/userinformation/login", {
      firstName,
      password
    }).then(result => {
      if (result.status === 200) {
        console.log('You have been logged in as user: ' +result.data[0].firstName)
        setAuthTokens(result.data);
        setLoggedIn(true);
      } else {
        setIsError(true);
      }
    }).catch(e => {
      setIsError(true);
    });
  }


  if (isLoggedIn) {
    return <Redirect to="/" />;
  }
```

Below is my **Hook** that contains the state

```
    const [authTokens, setAuthTokens] = useState();

  const setTokens = (data) => {
    localStorage.setItem("authTokens", JSON.stringify(data));
    setAuthTokens(data);
  }

  useEffect(()=> {
    let jsonToken = localStorage.getItem('authTokens', JSON.stringify(authTokens))
    console.log('JSON TOKEN  -----' + jsonToken)
    setAuthTokens(jsonToken)
  })
```

How can i set the state **authTokens** with the `local storage` variable on load so that when I refresh the state isnt empty so i dont get logged out on page reload. Also to mention The **context provider** is set up as so:

```
<AuthContext.Provider value={{ authTokens, setAuthTokens: setTokens}}>
   <ProtectedRoute path="/" exact component={ProfileBox}/>
</AuthContext.Provider>
```

Comment: What happens if you change the validation of your protected route to: `(authTokens || localStorage.getItem("authTokens")) ? (...` ?

Comment: Thanks so much, the amount of ways you can solve a problem is what got me into development. This def worked!

Comment: I posted a detailed answer instead of just a comment, please read it if you want a detailed explanation of what happens, and choose it as a correct answer if it helps :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `authTokens` is `undefined` when your component *mounts*, so the logic of your **Protected route** is evaluating to the `Redirect` portion of your code, causing the redirection to `/login`.

React will remove `componentWillMount` hook, so, the solution I found to this specific problem, is to check also for the token in the `localStorage`, instead of just checking for the state `authTokens`.

This way, your code will be able to evaluate that you have the token (even before the first component update).

The code of your `Protected Route` may look like this:

```
<Route
    {...rest}
    render={
        props=>
            (authTokens || localStorage.getItem("authTokens")) ? (
                <Component {...props}/>
            ) : (
                <Redirect
                    to ={
                        {
                            pathname: '/login',
                            state: {
                                from: props.location
                            }
                        }
                    }
                />
```

Other possible solutions are:

- Using Context
- Using Redux

But I think that if you just want to protect private routes, this solution is sufficient

Comment: been a minute, but would like to add to this - it seems like doing the `|| localStorage.getItem("authTokens")` check is the way to go *even if* using React Context. I have my AuthProvider which wraps RouterProvider (react-router v6). In my createBrowserRouter I'm fetching tokens and setting them to the localStorage. Since I can't update my context provider from within the router file, I can't update the "isAuth" in my provider in that first/initial render hence the OR checking for localStorage helps with the initial render. Subsequent page refreshes then get the value from the provider.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a **hook** that checks that the `localstorage` contains the **token**, if it doesn't exist the user isn't authenticated, so you can redirect him to **logIn**, else the user can access the `ProtectedRoutes`.

Maybe you can reuse your **hook** inside the `ProtectedRoute` component and handle it just there.

**ProtectedRoute**

Lets say that your component **Login** is the page that you want to redirect if the user isn't `auth`. And lets say that you are using `react-router` or something to handle the routes and redirections.

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({component, ...options}) => {
   const [isAuth ] = useAuth();
   let conditionalComponent = Login;
   if( isAuth ){
     conditionalComponent = component;
   }
   return <Route {...options} component={conditionalComponent} />
}
```

**useAuth**

```
const useAuth = () => {
 let [isAuth, handleAuthorized] = useState(false);

 useEffect( () => {
   if( checkLocalStorageToken() ){
    handleAuthorized( true );
   }  
   else {
    handleAuthorized(false)
   }
  return [ isAuth ]
 }, [ checkLocalStorageToken() ]);

}
```

I've been used this pattern and works good, i hope that i can share the main idea so you can implement it in your case.